# Windows 11 Grinds to a (almost) halt every few hours

Tags: performance, windows-11

I have a weird issue with a brand-new Windows 11 install that I am struggling to track down.

My OS is on an M.2 SSD, but I have moved my Users directory (using RegEdit) to `D:\Users`, a raid 5 mirror of 3 SATA HDDs.

I have multiple user profiles on it (Personal/Work), and the personal one is signed into its Microsoft account. Other than that, there aren't really any other differences between the accounts (apart from the running apps, of course).

I have both accounts running simultaneously to switch users between them when needed.

The problem, which seems to happen every few hours, is that the computer starts to slow down and eventually gets too slow to be usable.

If I log into my personal profile (connected to the windows account) and log out of it, the computer picks back up, and it all seems fine again. I log back into my personal account - and it's still all good - for a few more hours.

I have kept an eye on Task Manager, and nothing was interesting on there (apart from maybe the system process, and once I saw System Interrupts at ~25% for a while).

My initial suspicion is failing disks on the RAID 5, and I have ordered additional disks to replace them. However, I am concerned that there may be something else at play.

I ran an error check on the raid array, which took 15/20 minutes and completed without issues. Under performance management, it showed the disk at ~100% usage for that period but didn't slow the system down.

When the system does slow down, the same disk also shows ~100% usage. I have also seen the average response time go into 20 seconds when the system is slow.

I am unsure if the system slowdown is causing the high disk usage, or vice versa.

I have tried switching everything off in my profile (including from the system tray) and leaving it running "empty" and the problem still recurs which is the strangest part and suggests it's something windows specific.

Any pointers or additional things to try greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are any of the partitions, the system partition or the array, almost full?

Comment: check task manager for clues.

Comment: Good point on disk space - C: has 432G free and the array(D:) has 553G free. As for task manager, apart from high disk usage on D:, and around 10% CPU on system, I am not able to see anything untoward :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

My problem was that Windows could not find drivers to install for several devices. It did not tell me about this, and I got no other errors or warnings.

Going into Device Manager, I found 20 - 30 devices with little exclamation mark on them.

Unfortunately, installing all the drivers I could find on the motherboard(ASUS) website or from Intel brought me no further.

In the end, I had to install DriverEasy, which went ahead and installed a whole bunch of drivers.

Since then, the computer has been behaving well :)